# Mensaje de error

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo, necesito pedirles el siguiente favor:}

Estoy corriendo el siguiente aplicativo básico basado en una función con el siguiente código:

```
FsuperfRect=function(){     #Nombre de la funcion = function(){     Corchete de apertura
  cat("Longitud de la base: ");   
  base=scan(n=1,quiet=TRUE)    #Quiet=FALSE, indica si queremos que indique en la consola la lectura
  cat("Longitud de la altura: ");     # Cuerpo de la función
  altura=scan(n=1,quiet=TRUE) 
  S=base*altura    #S -->Superficie_del_rectangulo= base*altura 
  cat("Superficie del rectángulo: ",S) 
}      # Corchete de clausura
FsuperfRect()    #Nombre de la funcion()
```

Pese a que pide los datos como por ejemplo (Los que tenemos programados):

Longitud de la base y Longitud de la altura:

Me muestra el siguiente error:

Error in scan(n = 1, quiet = TRUE) :
scan() expected 'a real', got 'FsuperfRect=function(){'

Agradezco colaboración de antemano, en este inconveniente.

Comment: He probado el código y no me ha dado error. Ha funcionado correctamente. Me ha salido un error parecido cuando en vez de meter un número he metido una letra.

Answer (score 1):

Si consultas la ayuda de la función mediante `?scan`, la firma de la función dice:

```
scan(file = "", what = double(), nmax = -1, n = -1, sep = "",
     quote = if(identical(sep, "\n")) "" else "'\"", dec = ".",
     skip = 0, nlines = 0, na.strings = "NA",
     flush = FALSE, fill = FALSE, strip.white = FALSE,
     quiet = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, multi.line = TRUE,
     comment.char = "", allowEscapes = FALSE,
     fileEncoding = "", encoding = "unknown", text, skipNul = FALSE)
```

Podemos ver que el parámetro `what` que define que tipo de dato se espera, por defecto `what = double()` vemos que espera un valor de coma flotante, lo cual hace que cualquier cosa que ingreses por consola que no sea un número válido de dará este error.

Para evitar esto podría seguir insistiendo en la carga hasta que el usuario decida ingresar un número válido:

```
input_number <- function(msg) {
  cat(msg)
  ret <- NULL  
  while(is.null(ret)) {
    tryCatch(
      ret <- scan(n=1, quiet=TRUE),
      error = function(e){cat("Debe ingresar un valor numérico!\n");cat(msg)}
    )
  }
  return(ret)
}

base <- input_number("Longitud de la base: ")
```

La función nueva `input_number()` itera pidiendo el ingreso del usuario hasta que se cumpla la condición de que lo ingresado sea un número, el error eventualmente debe capturarse mediante `tryCatch()`